# Condição "if" não entra

Tags: javascript, if, condição

Por que não funciona esse tipo de condição no JavaScript?

```
if (permissoes[0] || permissoes[5] || permissoes[10] || permissoes[15] || permissoes[20] || permissoes[25] || permissoes[30] || permissoes[35] == "0") {
                valorModulo1 = "0";
            } else {
                valorModulo1 = "1";
            }
```

Esse *array* `permissões` sempre retorna 0 ou 1, eu quero que se algum elemento desses ai for 1 ele retorna `valorModulo1 = "1"` caso todos sejam zero retorna `valorModulo1="0"`, só que quando eu altero o valor do *array* para 1 ele não entra no `else`.

Comment: Já tentou `permissoes[0] == 1` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que é isto que quer:

```
if (permissoes[0] == "0" && permissoes[5] == "0" && permissoes[10] == "0" && permissoes[15] == "0" && permissoes[20] == "0" && permissoes[25] == "0" && permissoes[30] == "0" && permissoes[35] == "0") {
    valorModulo1 = "0";
} else {
    valorModulo1 = "1";
}
```

Tem um erro que você não está comparando os valores, a não ser no último, e pior em JavaScript tem caso que pode funcionar por coincidência e te enganar.

Mas além disso se você ler a especificação que colocou na pergunta todos dever ser 0 para dar 0, ora, todo quer dizer que eles precisam ser ligados com um **E** e não um **OU** que permitira que apenas um já servisse. Assim se um for falso, tudo será falso e cairá no `else`.

```js
let valorModulo1;
let permissoes = new Array(36);
for (let i = 0; i < 36; i++) permissoes[i] = "0";

if (permissoes[0] == "0" && permissoes[5] == "0" && permissoes[10] == "0" && permissoes[15] == "0" && permissoes[20] == "0" && permissoes[25] == "0" && permissoes[30] == "0" && permissoes[35] == "0") {
    valorModulo1 = "0";
} else {
    valorModulo1 = "1";
}

console.log(valorModulo1);
permissoes[0] = "1";

if (permissoes[0] == "0" && permissoes[5] == "0" && permissoes[10] == "0" && permissoes[15] == "0" && permissoes[20] == "0" && permissoes[25] == "0" && permissoes[30] == "0" && permissoes[35] == "0") {
    valorModulo1 = "0";
} else {
    valorModulo1 = "1";
}

console.log(valorModulo1);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Operators/ConditionAnd.js).

Answer (score 1):

Isso vai ser interpretado da seguinte forma:

Se *permissoes[0]* for um valor *[truthy](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)*, ou *permissoes[5]* for um valor *truthy*, e assim por diante, e não se algum desses é == "0".

O que você quer fazer é algo assim:

```
if(permissoes[0] || permissoes[5] ... permissoes[35]) {
   valorModulo1 = "1";
} else {
   valorModulo1 = "0";
```

}